# Unable to find 'https://{endpoint}/vision/v3.1/read/analyze[?language]' URL in cognitive services in azure

Tags: azure, outlook, computer-vision, azure-web-app-service, vision

**Recently I've subscribed for the azure computer vision services. I'm able to find endpoint and subscription key, but unable to find the OCR or URL similar to 'https://{endpoint}/vision/v3.1/read/analyze[?language]'. The location is central India. Can anyone please help me with this?**

Comment: How's going? Has your issue get solved?

Comment: It's working with vision 2.1

Comment: Glad to know your issue has been solved, pls accept my post if it is helpful for you and close this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your computer vision services region is central India, your OCR request URL should be:

```
POST https://centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3.1/ocr?language=unk&detectOrientation=true
```

For more details see the [official API reference here](https://centralindia.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-1-ga/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499f20d/console). You can also find `read` method here.

My test result:
[image]